# django-registration user activation conflicts with "deleted" inactive users

Tags: django-registration

Recently I've been looking into options for user registration using activation steps and came across the django-registration project.

Basically, the problem I noticed walking thru the code is the following and I don't know what's the "cheapest" way to solve it:

There is an ambiguity between "deleted" users (marked inactive - that is being suggested in number of sources), inactive users that just didn't activate their account (but activation has not expired yet) and ones with expired activation.

All these users in auth_user db have is_active=False

To distinguish between "valid" and "invalid" users any of user db queries should go also to user's profile and check for couple of things: i.e. the following are valid users:

- user.is_active=False AND user.get_profile().activated != ACTIVATED AND not_expired_yet
- user.is_active=True

This basically impacts all the query operations on users objects if one wants to consider only valid users.

The reason I liked the profile extension over inheritance from User model (that creates SQL JOIN queries) was to avoid extra JOIN queries wherever I don't necessarily need to access user's profile fields.

So I guess to make long story short - two questions:

1. What would be your suggestions for django-registration like approach to solve the ambiguity? QuerySet.select_related is the most I could think of that will basically end up in JOIN for every query on userdb.
2. How to nicely wrap the direct calls to django.auth.contrib.User.objects methods like filter,get,exclude so that they take into account only the valid users? The best I could think of was to go over RegistrationProfile method even for user queries...

Any feedback appreciated